# Saving each worksheet as individual pdf files from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying figure out how to modify the code I came across (can be found below). So instead of it making the worksheets as pages to pdf, I would want it to make them as individual pdf files. It should ass well avoid certain list of names for example:

- "pricing",
- "cover" and
- "important",

and it should take the name from the sheet it's making the pdf from. I'm at a dead end right now, so might as well ask.

Here's to code (This code selects the file the Excels are in, makes you choose where the pdf files go to and loops trough every worksheet in the folder (For instance i got 50 files with 3 sheets each and I need each sheet as their own pdf:s to be an attachment for an invoice)):

```
Sub ExcelSaveAsPDF()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim xStrFile1, xStrFile2 As String
    Dim xWbk As Workbook
    Dim xSFD, xRFD As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xRPath, xWBName As String
    Dim xBol As Boolean
    
    Set xSFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With xSFD
        .Title = "Please select the folder contains the Excel files you want to "
        convert:"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    End With
    
    If xSFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    xSPath = xSFD.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    
    Set xRFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With xRFD
        .Title = "Please select a destination folder to save the converted files:"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    End With
    
    If xRFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    xRPath = xRFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    strPath = xSPath & "\"
    xStrFile1 = Dir(strPath & "*.*")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Do While xStrFile1 <> ""
        xBol = False
        If Right(xStrFile1, 3) = "xls" Then
            Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & xStrFile1)
            xbwname = Replace(xStrFile1, ".xls", "_pdf")
            xBol = True
        ElseIf Right(xStrFile1, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & xStrFile1)
            xbwname = Replace(xStrFile1, ".xlsx", "_pdf")
            xBol = True
        ElseIf Right(xStrFile1, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & xStrFile1)
            xbwname = Replace(xStrFile1, ".xlsm", "_pdf")
            xBol = True
        End If
        
        If xBol Then
            xWbk.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xRPath & xbwname & ".pdf"
            xWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        
        xStrFile1 = Dir
    
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `convert:"` is that a typo?

Comment: Is this the same Q? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72566044/need-advice-assistance-vba-that-saves-multiple-excel-sheets-to-separate-pdf-file  … you may want to try to understand how both codes from the previous post work.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to U/Jimm_kirkk for helping with this project.

My original reddit Post: [Here][1]!

Code explanation:

1. Makes you select the folder that contains the Excel files and where the pdf files go to.
2. After that it makes every sheet ad individual pdf.
3. In the code is a place you can set a list of names to avoid printing as pdf.
4. Takes around a minute per 10 excel files.

The code:

```
Sub ExcelSaveAsPDF()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim xStrFile1, xStrFile2 As String
    Dim xWbk As Workbook
    Dim xSFD, xRFD As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xRPath, xWBName As String
    Dim xBol As Boolean
    
    Set xSFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With xSFD
        .Title = "Please select the folder contains the Excel files you want to convert:"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    End With
    
    If xSFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    xSPath = xSFD.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    
    Set xRFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With xRFD
        .Title = "Please select a destination folder to save the converted files:"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    End With
    
    If xRFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    xRPath = xRFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    strPath = xSPath & "\"
    xStrFile1 = Dir(strPath & "*.*")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Do While xStrFile1 <> ""
        xBol = False
        If Right(xStrFile1, 3) = "xls" Then
            Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & xStrFile1)
            'modified xbwname to be simplified name
            xbwname = Replace(xStrFile1, ".xls", "")
            xBol = True
        ElseIf Right(xStrFile1, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & xStrFile1)
            'modified xbwname to be simplified name
            xbwname = Replace(xStrFile1, ".xlsx", "")
            xBol = True
        ElseIf Right(xStrFile1, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & xStrFile1)
            'modified xbwname to be simplified name
            xbwname = Replace(xStrFile1, ".xlsm", "")
            xBol = True
        End If
        
        If xBol Then
            'modified here to install sub main_ExportPDF()
            Sheet_ExportPDF xWbk, xRPath & xbwname
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            xWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        
        xStrFile1 = Dir
    
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Sheet_ExportPDF(wb As Workbook, fname As String)
'Purpose: determine sheets to be exported to pdf

    'store base workbook name
    Dim baseWB As String
    baseWB = fname

    'user to define what names to avoid by adding to string
    Const NTA As String = "pricing,cover,important"

    'build array of names to avoid
    Dim NamesToAvoid As Variant
    NamesToAvoid = Split(NTA, ",")
    
    'process visible worksheets and compare to NamesToAvoid, export the
    'sheets that are not in conflict with user's list to avoid
    Dim ws As Worksheet, blnConflict As Boolean, i As Long
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        'determine if sheet is visible
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            'loop through user's list to avoid
            For i = LBound(NamesToAvoid) To UBound(NamesToAvoid)
                'if on the avoidance list, set bln and exit loop
                If UCase(ws.Name) = Trim(UCase(NamesToAvoid(i))) Then
                    blnConflict = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            'process appropriate safe sheets
            fname = baseWB & "_" & ws.Name & ".pdf"
            If Not blnConflict Then ExportPDF ws, fname Else blnConflict = False
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

Function ExportPDF(sht As Worksheet, fname As String)
'Purpose: facilitate exporting to pdf
        
    'execute the exporting with some basic parameters set to user's needs
    sht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fname, quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        includedocproperties:=True, ignoreprintareas:=True, openafterpublish:=False
        
End Function
```

good luck!